# Swift Set Value for Key of another Key

Tags: swift

I'm working on a project where I have XML responses being converted to an instance of an object. For sake of this question, root elements are mapped to "Parameter" and child elements are mapped to "Subparameter" with the class setup like this.

```
class MyClass : NSObject {
  var Parameter = Parameter()
}

class Parameter: NSObject {
  var Subparameter = String()
}
```

My question is this...  How do I set the value of MyClass.Parameter.Subparameter using setValue(value, key)?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: MyClass is just an example.  My actual class has been redacted. The actual class has about 15 parameters and two that have sub parameters.  Each parameter or "key" will have only one value.  Does that help?

Comment: why wouldn't you just have one class with a dictionary that maps key to values where keys are the root elements

Comment: That's getting closer ... This would be much clearer if you edit your question and provide a hypothetical XML with one parameter with subparameter and one without, and then what the corresponding `MyClass` would look like for these two sample parameters. In an effort to spare of the gory details (which is good), you've reduced this to something so overly simplistic that we can't understand the question. Give us a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JoshHamet - I actually agree with OP that a subclassed object is often much better than a dictionary. Dictionaries are best when the developer has no way of knowing what the possible key values at runtime might be. But if you know what those properties are going to be, a strongly typed subclass is much better.

Comment: @Rob fair enough, didn't realize there was a set number of keys values. pretty much confused at the question then. To me, if he wants to set a value of sub parameter, it's as simply as myClass.Parameter.SubParameter = "" where myClass is an instance of MyClass

Comment: @JoshHamet - I _think_ he's asking how to do KVC on object with properties, of which some of these properties will have subproperties. It's hard to tell until he clarifies the question.

Comment: Hi guys, great discussion.  I am heading to the store and I will add more code when I get back.  But to clear up some confusion, the XML does have a set number of elements and sub elements that I'm trying to map to a class.  More to come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your classes subclass `NSObject`, you enjoy key-value coding (KVC) and you can do `object.setValue(forKey:)`.

If you're dealing with XML with some elements that have sub-elements, the trick is how to let the parser keep track upon which object to perform the `setValue(forKey:)`. I personally will frequently maintain a stack of objects:

Consider this XML:

```
<people>
    <person>
        <name>Rob</name>
        <address>
            <address1>1 Main Street</address1>
            <address2 />
            <city>Pasadena</city>
            <state>CA</state>
        </address>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Rachel</name>
        <address>
            <address1>1 Broadway</address1>
            <address2>Apt 1</address2>
            <city>New York</city>
            <state>NY</state>
        </address>
    </person>
</people>
```

And consider this class hierarchy:

```
class Person : NSObject {
    var name: String?
    var address: Address?
}

class Address: NSObject {
    var address1: String?
    var address2: String?
    var city: String?
    var state: String?
}
```

So, when I enter `<person>`, I add a `Person` object to my stack. When I exit `</person>`, I pop a the `Person` off the stack and update the parent object accordingly. Likewise, when I enter and exist `<address>` and `</address>`, I push and pop `Address` objects off my stack, again updating the parent object accordingly. With this pattern, at any given point in time, the last item in the stack will always be the "current" object, so whenever I encounter an element other that `Person` or `Address`, I just update the value for that current object with whatever string value I received.

So, you can then parse that with:

```
var results: [Person]?
private var objectStack = [NSObject]()
private var currentString: String?

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    if elementName == "people" {
        objectStack = [Person]()
    } else if elementName == "person" {
        objectStack.append(Person())
    } else if elementName == "address" {
        objectStack.append(Address())
    } else {
        currentString = String()
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    currentString? += string
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if let foundString = currentString {
        objectStack.last?.setValue(foundString, forKey: elementName)
        currentString = nil
    } else if let lastObject = objectStack.last where lastObject is Address {
        objectStack.removeLast()
        if objectStack.isEmpty {
            results = lastObject as? [Person]
        } else {
            objectStack.last?.setValue(lastObject, forKey: elementName)
        }
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {
    print(parseError)
}
```

Now this is a rudimentary example. I am not, for example, checking to see if that current object has a property for that `elementName`, so the above will crash if the XML included element names that didn't correspond to an object's properties. Nor am I checking the type of the element property to do the appropriate conversion of the string value that was parsed. All of this is easily added, but I wanted to keep my example as concise as possible.

But it illustrates the basic idea: You need to

- keep track of some "stack" of custom objects so you know to which object you are updating in `didEndElement`;
- have special handling in `didStartElement` to know whether you want to instantiate a custom object and push it on to your stack, or whether you're going to parse some text value to just update the current object;
- have special handling in `didEndElement` to know whether you're updating a value of custom object or whether you finished with some custom object, popping it off the stack and updating some value in the parent custom object (that is now at the end of the stack).

If this stack concept is too confusing, you can accomplish the same sort of thing by keeping track of all sorts of properties depending upon what level of the XML tree you happen to be at. I personally find the stack model compelling.

Anyway, once you take care of keeping track of where you are in the XML tree, you can then do the `setValue(forKey:)` to update a value whether a top level element or some child element.

Comment: Thank you Rob, I'm trying to wrap my head around your answer and test it.  I'll let you know my result.

Comment: Hi Rob, I was finally able to get back to this.  I probably should have mentioned that I am not using the native NSXMLParser, I'm using AEXML.  However, I did want to validate your solution so I built a temporary project.  I don't know much about NSXMLParser so forgive me if this is way off.  I added the following to your example to run it.  

let parser = NSXMLParser (.....)
parser.parse()

however the functions you built are never getting called.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I made a bonehead mistake and forgot to put in parser.delegate = self.  It worked after that, thanks!